# Homework: Noise in a circuit

Tags: power-supply, noise

I had this problem in a homework assignment:

> If the noise in a 5 V voltage line and ground for a five volt circuit is of the order of 10 mV, for a first order system, how many time constants will you wait to be sure you reached the practically achievable final steady state values?

Does this mean that the noise in any circuit eventually dies out and that every circuit reaches a steady state ?
This would have been easy if the circuit can be modeled using capacitors and inductors but I have not been able to think of such an arrangement.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Andyaka Didn't make sense to me too.

Comment: Is this question taken from some textbook? or if you were asked this in a course, which book are you using? I don't guarantee that I would know the answer, but it can help others answering your question.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist I couldn't find it in any textbook. It is just an assignment problem. The recommended textbook for the course is -- Engineering Circuit Analysis by Hayt, Kemmerly, 
Durbin, 7th edition, Tata McGraw Hill.

Comment: A badly worded homework question. *First order* would suggest a single RC circuit (time constant = RC). My **best guess** would be that it is asking how long (in time constants) would it take a 5V step input to go from 0V to 4.99V output (i.e within 10mV of the 5V). At least that would be a solvable calculation.

Comment: @JImDearden That seems plausible

Comment: Yes. They're basically asking, "How long do you need to wait until the remaining offset that's due to the transient response is indistinguishable from noise?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that what the teacher meant was:

Suppose there is a first order filter (i.e. RC filter) and that you're working on a real environment (noisy, white noise). Now, in the absence of signal at the input, the output will be just a noisy, filtered signal. So, the proper question should be "how much do I have to wait until I can say that the output arrived to a steady state?"

You have to think of noise as the "input" for your filter.

So far, it doesn't depend on the power supply, but on the filter (i.e. the time constant = RC). 
As a rule of thumb, you should wait for 4 or 5 constant times (RC) until the output reaches steady state.

Hope this helps!